# Is there a way to preprocess input to tar?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, tar

Something like this would be great:

```
tar cvzf file.tgz input_dir --exclude '.*' --preprocess "tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'"
```

Comment: Would this `preprocess` step act on the filenames or the file contents?

Comment: Ideally both. It seems that --to-command only works for `tar xf`. Also it doesn't have access to the filename.

Comment: If you're just looking for a tool to process the filenames, you can do something like `find input_dir | tr whatever | tar cvzf file.tgz -T -` to tell `tar` what files to include. Add whatever exclusions at the `find` level. As far as the data, I think you'll need to create temp files as `tar` stores metadata and other information so it can't recreate that from standard in.

Comment: Yes, i think you're probably right. Thanks!